# CSS3 Class Inherits Div Opacity in Safari 9.x?

Tags: html, css, animation, safari, css-animations

[W-I-P DEMO](http://webergraphicdesign.com/wgd/indexTEST.php) (Reduced clutter and added "Correct" and "Incorrect" labels on cube faces for clarity.) An animated CSS cube with 4 autoplay slideshows and animated text (on hover) on each pane works as expected on all 4 cube faces in current versions of FF and Chrome (not yet tested in others), but Safari (both desktop and mobile versions) appear to be overriding the "slidetext" class with the "@keyframes slideshow" opacity (i.e., at 40% of the cube rotation), resulting in opacity-faded text on 2 of the cube faces ~1/2-way through the cube rotation. Where are my coding errors, or could this possibly be a Safari glitch?

HTML

```
<div id="cubecontainer">
  <div class="shadowcontainer">
    <div class="shadow">
      <div>&nbsp;</div>
    </div><!-- end of shadow -->
  </div><!-- end of shadowcontainer -->
  <div class="cubewrapper">
    <div class="cube">
        <div class="front"><a href="websites.php">
            <div class="slideshowcontainerW">
              <img class="slide" src="./images/cube/cubeW1.png" alt="W1" />
              <img class="slide" src="./images/cube/cubeW2.png" alt="W2" />
              <img class="slide" src="./images/cube/cubeW3.png" alt="W3" />
              <img class="slide" src="./images/cube/cubeW4.png" alt="W4" />
            </div><span class="slidetext">WEB SITES</span></a>
        </div>
        <div class="back"><a href="extraordinary.php">
            <div class="slideshowcontainerE">
              <img class="slide" src="./images/cube/cubeE1.png" alt="E1" />
              <img class="slide" src="./images/cube/cubeE2.png" alt="E2" />
              <img class="slide" src="./images/cube/cubeE3.png" alt="E3" />
              <img class="slide" src="./images/cube/cubeE4.png" alt="E4" />
            </div><span class="slidetext">EXTRAORDINARY</span></a>
        </div>
        <div class="top">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="bottom">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="left"><a href="profile.php">
            <div class="slideshowcontainerP">
              <img class="slide" src="./images/cube/cubeP1.png" alt="P1" />
              <img class="slide" src="./images/cube/cubeP2.png" alt="P2" />
              <img class="slide" src="./images/cube/cubeP3.png" alt="P3" />
              <img class="slide" src="./images/cube/cubeP4.png" alt="P4" />
            </div><span class="slidetext">PROFILE</span></a>
        </div>
        <div class="right"><a href="logos.php">
            <div class="slideshowcontainerL">
              <img class="slide" src="./images/cube/cubeL1.png" alt="L1" />
              <img class="slide" src="./images/cube/cubeL2.png" alt="L2" />
              <img class="slide" src="./images/cube/cubeL3.png" alt="L3" />
              <img class="slide" src="./images/cube/cubeL4.png" alt="L4" />
            </div><span class="slidetext">LOGOS</span></a>
        </div>      
    </div><!-- end of cube -->
  </div><!-- end of cubewrapper -->
</div><!-- end of cubecontainer -->
```

CSS

```
#cubecontainer {
    float:right;
    padding-left:50px;
    padding-right:50px;
    padding-top:10px;
    padding-bottom:220px;
}
#cubecontainer:hover div {
    animation-play-state: paused;
}
.cubewrapper {
    perspective: 800px;
    perspective-origin: 50% 100px;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.cube {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.cube p {
  padding: 40px 0;
}
.cube div {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    opacity: 0.95;
}
.back {
  transform: translateZ(-100px) rotateY(180deg);
  background-color: #FFF;
}
.right {
  transform: rotateY(-270deg) translateX(100px);
  transform-origin: top right;
  background-color: #FFF;
}
.left {
  transform: rotateY(270deg) translateX(-100px);
  transform-origin: center left;
  background-color: #FFF;
}
.top {
  transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateY(-100px);
  transform-origin: top center;
  background-color: #FFF;
}
.bottom {
  transform: rotateX(90deg) translateY(100px);
  transform-origin: bottom center;
  background-color: #FFF;
}
.front {
  transform: translateZ(100px);
  background-color: #FFF;
}
@keyframes cubespin {
  from { transform: rotateY(0); }
  to { transform: rotateY(-360deg); }
}
.cube, .shadow {
  animation: cubespin 16s linear infinite;
}
.shadowcontainer {
  perspective: 800px;
  perspective-origin: 50% 100px;
}
.shadow {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.shadow div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  top: 0px;
  opacity: 0.98;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 50px 10px #000;
  transform: rotateX(90deg) translateY(100px);
  transform-origin: bottom center;
}
/*END CUBE*/
/*BEGIN CODE FOR SLIDESHOW ON CUBE FACES*/
.slideshowcontainerE, .slideshowcontainerL, .slideshowcontainerP, .slideshowcontainerW {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
.slide {
  position: absolute;
  animation: slideshow 20s infinite;
  opacity: 0;
}
.slidetext {
    width:195px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding-right:5px;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 1em;
    color:#FFF;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #F00;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,.75);
    border: none;
}
.slidetext:hover {
    width:195px;
    margin:0px auto;
    padding-right:5px;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 1em;
    color:#F00;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #FFF;
    background:rgba(255,200,100,.75);
    border: none;
    transition: color, background .5s ease-in;
}
@keyframes slideshow {
  25% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  40% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
img:nth-child(1) {
  animation-delay: 15s;
}
img:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 10s;
}
img:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: 5s;
}
img:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: 0s;
}
/*END CODE FOR SLIDESHOW ON CUBE FACES*/
```

Comment: When I tried to run this on Safari 9.1 on my mbp, it immediately crashed Safari... Although I did see the opacity problem, it was struggling to render things in general

Comment: So far, the demo page has been tested in Safari 9.1 on a 2008 & 2012 MBP running OS 10.11.4, iPhone 6 (running iOS 9.3.1), FF 45.0.2, Chrome 50.x, and IE 11.x (which can't properly render the cube since "transform-style: preserve-3d;" was never implemented), and none of the browsers crashed. The demo page exclusively uses CSS (i.e., without any javascript, jquery, etc.), so is it possible that excessive CPU load (and/or high demand on the video card, etc.) caused the crash?

Comment: Possibly, this is running on an external screen, and El Capitain has had some dramas with it since the upgrade. It could be a combination of load and my dodgy drivers